# react native and expo issues

Tags: react-native, expo

why there is no android folder in expo workspace  can i make some native tasks 
i want to make some style on Picker component , i read that i must do that for android natively , but i can't figure out how , for generating APK is it true that with expo you must do this on their server ? they can keep a copy of my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you created app using `create-react-native-app` command, then it uses expo where there is no facility for native coding.
If your app need of native programming you can make eject project using `npm run eject` command.
Result of this is similar to app created using `react-native init` where you can find `android` and `ios` folders and do changes to native code either in android or ios.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hello.. I have a question that If i made a project through expo start and then at the middle I require some codes to be run on android and iOS folders. Then what to do ? And after that will the expo modules work again? And after changing into the iOS and android I again want to go to expo and start development again. Then what to do?